# Testing ngOnChanges with SimpleChanges in Angular 2

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular2-directives, angular2-testing

I have the code below and I need to know how I could use `spyon` with `previousValue` and `currentValue` in my test to coverage the conditional `if (cur !== prev && cur === 100)`.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['highlightData'] && !changes['highlightData'].isFirstChange()) {
        const prev: any = changes['highlightData'].previousValue;
        const cur: any = changes['highlightData'].currentValue;

        if (cur !== prev && cur === 100) {
            this._render.setElementClass(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'animate', true);

            setTimeout(() => {
                this._render.setElementClass(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'animate', false);
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

2 methods are provided in this [blog](https://medium.com/@christophkrautz/testing-ngonchanges-in-angular-components-bbb3b4650ee8), one is to manually call it and other is to use a wrapper to trigger it by framework